# how to keep $s1array = file_get_contents("T-Splitsing.txt");, $s1array

Tags: php, html

I am currently trying to save this in a file. But it wont work.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
My goal when I push the `verturen` button that I save the values,
`r`, `o` or `g` in the text file, and after that save it in `$s1array`.
After that if I press download that he load the `$s1array` into the text file.
I want to keep the new value of `$s1array` for the rest of the time.

(here is my code)

```
    <form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Versturen">
    <select name="state1sl1">
      <option name="groen" value="g">groen</option>}
      <option name="oranje" value="o">oranje</option>
      <option name="rood" value="r">rood</option>}
    </select>

    <select name="state1sl2">
      <option name="groen" value="g">groen</option>}
      <option name="oranje" value="o">oranje</option>
      <option name="rood" value="r">rood</option>}
    </select>

    <select name="state1sl3">
      <option name="groen" value="g">groen</option>}
      <option name="oranje" value="o">oranje</option>
      <option name="rood" value="r">rood</option>}
    </select>
    </form>

<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="download" value="download">
</form>


    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    $_name1 = $_POST['state1sl1'];
    $_name2 = $_POST['state1sl2'];
    $_name3 = $_POST['state1sl3'];
    $my_File = 'T-Splitsing.txt';
    $fh = fopen($my_File, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $_name1);
    fwrite($fh, $_name2);
    fwrite($fh, $_name3);
    fclose($fh);
    $s1array = file_get_contents("T-Splitsing.txt");
    }

  if(isset($_POST['download'])){


   $file = 'T-Splitsing.txt';

     if (file_exists($file)) {
     $my_File = 'T-Splitsing.txt';
     $fh = fopen($my_File, 'w') or die("can't open file");
     fwrite($fh, $s1array);
     fclose($fh);

    ?>
```

Comment: Nice localized version ;) You can store the data you want to keep in a `$_SESSION` for keepsake to work with it on other pages. But the "*for the rest of the time*"-part is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Allendar, I meant, if I press download that the data in $s1array will be put in the T-Splitsing.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, since PHP does not remember state. Each time you submit a form, this is a new HTTP request. Nevertheless, what you could do (as I see that you are saving the data into "T-Splitsing.txt") is to simply load the data from the file and send it to the user. The "download" part of the code would become:

```
 if(isset($_POST["download"])){
   $file = "T-Splitsing.txt";
   header("Content-Type: text/plain");
   header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file."\""); 
   readfile($file);
 }
```

Comment: Hello Tomor,
I know how to download the text file.
But my problem is it wont remember $s1array
so if I press download an empty text file will be downloaded.
I would like to know if there is a way to save $s1array?

Comment: If you simply want to "re-save" the value of the array into the text file, store it in a session variable like `$_SESSION['s1array'] = file_get_contents(...)`, and then access it using `$_SESSION['s1array'];` from inside `if(isset($_POST["download"]))`

Comment: Hello,

I echo'd it and it worked but when i want to write it in a text file it doesnt work
if(isset($_POST['download'])){


$file = 'T-Splitsing.txt';

if (file_exists($file)) {
  $my_File = 'T-Splitsing.txt';
  $fh = fopen($my_File, 'w') or die("can't open file");
  fwrite($fh, $_session['s1array']);
  fclose($fh);

Comment: the name should be all caps: **$_SESSION**. Use this, when setting the value, as well as getting it. Also do not forget to call `session_start()` at the beginning of the file